# Which files are generated when executing `dart2js`? and why?

Tags: dart, dart2js

dart2js probably generates `.js.map`, `.js.deps` and `.precompiled.js`.

What's the purpose of them? and I donno why `dart2js` doens't remove them after finishing compile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All files are generated by [dart2js](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html) on purpose:

*.js*: The JavaScript output of your application

*.precompiled.js*: The JavaScript output but with [content security policy (CSP) support](http://dartbug.com/13547)

*.js.map*: source map file used for debugging the JavaScript code in the browser. It contains a mapping from JavaScript to Dart code lines.

*.js.deps*: contains a list list of all references files used for compilation, prop ably for debugging but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think `.precompiled.js` is the only thing that I really necessary. and others is not necessary for the real web application.

Comment: Not for the final deployed version, but .js.map is very usefull during development / debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I believe is correct at the time I write this:

- `.js` - the main JavaScript output of dart2js

  Convention is to us the -o option to set the generated Javascript filename to end with `.dart.js` to differentiate generated Javascript from explicit Javascript in the Dart project. E.g.:

  `dart2js -o main.dart.js main.dart`

  `pub-build` does that by default. The [dart.js](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/browser/lib/dart.js) file assumes this convention is used. Sample Dart .gitignore files often include `*.dart.js`.
- `.js.map` - provides source maps from JavaScript to Dart that make debugging easier
- `.js.deps` - what files were used when compiling with dart2js
- `.info.json` - json file with information about the generated code (if `--dump-info` specified)
- `.js_1.part.js`, `.js_2.part.js` etc. - parts of deferred imports

  Sample Dart .gitignore files often include `*.js_` to cover these files.
- The `--deferred-map` option will generate a json file that you must provide a file name for.
- `.precompiled.js` is no longer produced by dart2js

See:

1. https://www.dartlang.org/tools/private-files.html
2. https://github.com/dart-lang/www.dartlang.org/issues/1496 for my conversation with the site authors on making some adjustments.
3. https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dart2js/
4. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Dart.gitignore.