# What is the .precompiled.js file dart2js produces?

Tags: javascript, compilation, dart, dart2js

There’s a `.precompiled.js` file along `.js` and `.js.map` files the dart2js compiler produces. Compiling the code

```
void main() {
  print('Hello, stranger.');
}
```

results in identical `.js` and `.precompiled.js` files except that the latter contains the extra lines:

```
function dart_precompiled($collectedClasses){var $desc
return[]}
```

A Google search reveals nothing except some obscure issues in the tracker, referencing something called CSP, which in itself is unsearchable.

So, what this `.precompiled.js` is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314796

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which files are generated when executing \`dart2js\`? and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314796/which-files-are-generated-when-executing-dart2js-and-why)